# CMake says c compiler is broken

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, firebreath

I've just attempted to use Firebreath and have followed their video tutorial for Windows and come across the error that says:

> Check for working C compiler using Visual Studio 10 -- broken

And then says:

> It fails with following output:
>  Change Dir:

And then lists the drive. This happens when running prep2010.cmd. I have found a post about it, but the forums won't let me log in and there is no answer. It's here: http://forum.firebreath.org/topic/274/?page=1#post-1117 and is exactly the same error, I believe. The last post talks about running prep2010 from inside the vs2010 command shell. What does that mean?

Has anyone else had this error or know how it is caused? I have no idea how to approach it.

Thankyou

Comment: Okay, first thing to clarify here is that this error comes from CMake (I reworded the subject so that maybe someone who knows the answer might see it)

Answer (score 7):

I know this is really old.. but in case someone else has this problem, the solution for me was to install service pack 1 for visual studio 2010

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment above, this is not "FireBreath" that is saying your compiler is broken; the prep command uses CMake to generate the project files, and it is from cmake that the error comes.

In your start menu where Visual Studio 2010 is there should be a "tools" or "utilities" subfolder and in there somewhere there is a "Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt" link.  That starts a command prompt with environment variables and path set up so that the vs2010 commands are all available.  The error you're seeing is indicating that for whatever reason, CMake is unable to find visual studio 2010.

I don't know if using the vs2010 command prompt will help or not; it doesn't have any trouble finding vs2010 on any of my boxes.  I can postulate that perhaps if you installed it to a nonstandard location, in a nonstandard way, or your registry got screwed up any of these things could potentially cause the issue that you are seeing.  Also if you don't have vs2010 installed it would certainly cause this issue =]

I'd recommend first trying the vs2010 command prompt; if that doesn't work, you may have to try uninstalling and reinstalling vs2010.  If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas, and maybe someone who knows more about cmake will have a suggestion :-(

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I tried the vs2010 command prompt but it did the same thing. Reading through the error it seems to be going to the right place. It seems to pick up a problem at bin/cl.exe in the VC folder of Visual Studio 10. When I run that it says I'm missing mspdl100.dll. And after adding that it still fails. Does your cl.exe run?

Comment: cl is the compiler it uses; yes, mine runs.  sounds like vs is borked on your system in some way that causes it to not work with cmake. :-/  Wish I had any other ideas for you

Answer (score 2):

I also had MSCV 2010 x64 on windows 7 and installing service pack one also helped.
Also make sure that all your external dependancies are (x64) versions:

MSVC version:
http://visual-studio-2010.en.malavida.com/

Gl&HF

Comment: Did you have the same issue as the OP reported?

Answer (score 2):

Service pack 1:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Configure cmake with generator: MSVC2010 x64

Comment: Actually he most likely does *not* want the x64 version as that would produce a 64 bit DLL and he probably wants a 32 bit one

Comment: Please help. Why is it that I can generate VisualStudio2010 for downloaded projects like rapidxml, wxWidgets and more, but the simple one example coming in CMake tutorial fails?!!! Do you think this is the same problem? I generated the Makefile for MinGW compiler and works, but then with Vistudio2010 it logs the error mentioned in this thread. But as I said any other project I have downloaded produces correct VStudio 2010 solutions. The basic project I am setting up is as the first version of the CMake tutorials.

Comment: BTW, I get exactly same behavior trying to generate VStudio2013 solutions.